# ViewPager Is Stuck Between Views after Disabling User Interaction for Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I recently implemented code in my app to allow the app to disable all user interaction while a boolean field is set to `true`. The purpose of doing this is to keep a user from interacting with the app while a vehicle is in motion. As suggested by other questions/answers I implemented this by overriding `dispatchTouchEvent` in my activity.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mLockedOut) {
        showLockedOutDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The problem with this code is that my app consists of multiple fragments displayed in a `ViewPager`. If user interaction is disabled while a user is swiping between pages, the `ViewPager` will become stuck between pages.

How can one prevent this from happening? I've posted my solution, but wonder if I didn't overlook some edge or corner case.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by only consuming `MotionEvent`s which are of type [`ACTION_DOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) or [`ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_POINTER_DOWN).

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!mLockedOut) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            showLockedOutDialog();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```